# Effect of Gambler's Ruin Bet Size on Duration

Tags: probability, gambling

Suppose we have a classic Gambler's Ruin problem as follows:

Person A starts with $100$ dollars, and will keep betting $10$ dollars each round until he either reaches $180$ dollars or goes broke, where $p$ is the probability he wins each round.

Now suppose he makes $5$ dollar bets each time instead, but has the same initial fortune and the same goal.

How can I explain why the expected number of games has to be more than doubled?

Comment: And if $p=0,1$?

Comment: $p$ can't be zero. $0<p<1$

Comment: Your step size got cut in half, so the number of steps at least doubled and if $p=\frac 1 2$ it quadrupled.

Comment: @A.S. But why is it more than doubled, and if p = .5, quadrupled?

Comment: Because when you lower you speed from 10 mph, it takes you twice as long to get to the destination and because of randomness it becomes a little bit more. For $p=\frac 1 2$ there no no drift, so you position no longer grows linearly but as $sqrt t$. For $p=\frac 1 2$ the exact result is $ET=ab$.